# Check if text was added to an element with the Firefox console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add text to a div and then check if it is added with the FF console.
The code I enter into the *console* is:

```
jQuery('<div id="method" style="display:none">').append("jonesy" + ',');
jQuery('<div id="method">').text()
```

I expect to get the string *jonesy,* returned, but I get displayed an empty string. Where is my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like:

```
jQuery('<div id="method" style="display:none">jonesy,</div>').appendTo('body');
jQuery('#method').text();
```

- Create the dyanmic div using `jQuery('<div id="method" style="display:none">jonesy,</div>')`.
- Attach the newly created div to DOM, using `.appendTo('body')`

[**FIDDLE DEMO #1**](http://jsfiddle.net/F8jmW/)

You can do in a better way like:

```
// Create a new dynamic div
var $div = jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'method',
    style: 'display:none',
    text: 'jonesy,'
});

// Append the new div to the DOM
$div.appendTo('body');

// Check the console for the text
console.log(jQuery("#method").text());
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO #2**](http://jsfiddle.net/fACFr/)

Answer (score 6):

Your syntax `jQuery('<div id="method">')` is creating a new DIV each time. Only the first one has the text added.

What you want is likely like this;

```
var myDiv = jQuery('<div id="method" style="display:none">'); // save the div in a var
myDiv.append("jonesy" + ','); // append to it
myDiv.text(); // read from the same DIV
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is a bit off my friend:

```
jQuery("div#method").append("jonesy" + ",");
console.log(jQuery("#method").text());
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems.  First, each jQuery call here is creating a separate div.

To refer to a previously-created div, reference it by selector, don't create a new one:

```
jQuery('<div id="method" style="display:none">').text("jonesy" + ',');
jQuery('#method').text()
```

but that won't really work, either, since the div was never added to the document. The second line looks for matches *within* the document.

Try:

```
jQuery('<div id="method" style="display:none">').
  text("jonesy" + ',').
  appendTo($(document.body));
jQuery('#method').text()
```

Comment: .appendTo() can take a native DOM object as argument, no need to wrap `document.body` in `$()` - also, seeing as you're chaining this far, why not continue to chain instead of selecting it by id?

Comment: I was following the original line of code - looks like the OP is in the console figuring out how selectors and creation work. In real code, I'd do just that... but this is more informative.

Answer (score 1):

I can spot two issues:

1. <del>If you want to [feed the `jQuery()` function with HTM](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-ownerDocument)L, it needs to be complete standalone HTML. `<div id="method"></div>` is correct, `<div id="method">` is not.</del>

   **Edit**: just tested and your code seems to work fine.
2. That syntax creates a new element. If you want to search for an existing element you need to use CSS selectors. However, your element is neither attached to the DOM nor saved in a variable, thus there's no easy way to reach it.

I suppose you want something like this:

```
var div = jQuery('<div id="method" style="display:none"></div>').append("jonesy" + ',');
div.text();
```